# Expired TweetDeck links

Tags: links, tweetdeck

In TweetDeck if you make a long tweet, it automatically shortens it and makes a link where the whole message can be read.

But I've noticed that if I go back about a week or more and try those links again, I get a 404 error.

Why is that? Is there a way to use a different link that won't expire?

Answer (score 2):

TweetDeck uses Deck.ly to allow users to write tweets longer than 140 characters. The problem you experience is because Deck.ly does not work as expected. Deck.ly is a service of TweetDeck (if you try to open deck.ly from your browser, it redirects to tweetdeck.com). You cannot change it from TweetDeck settings, but you can disable it. Just uncheck the following option in settings:

[image: settings]

Furthermore, I recommend you reading the following article: [If you can’t say it in 140 characters, say it elsewhere.](http://blog.chron.com/techblog/2011/02/if-you-cant-say-it-in-140-characters-say-it-elsewhere/)

Comment: I agree with the article - " If you can’t say it in 140 characters, say it elsewhere."

Comment: What you said doesn't seem to agree with the fact that for new tweets I can open the links from a browser.